# Creating an XML from tiered class structure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, xml-serialization

I am trying to create an XML file based off of a class setup. I'm having trouble getting it to work, at the moment I am not getting any errors or exceptions just unintended results.

I was expecting something like this

```xml
<armyListing><army name="">
<unit-category name="">
<unit-type name="">
<unit name="" composition="" weapon-skill="" etc></unit>
</unit-type>
<unit-type name="">
<unit name="" composition="" weapon-skill="" etc></unit>
</unit-type>
</unit-category>
</army>
</armyListing>
```

but I just get `<armyListing><army/></armyListing>`

I thought I may have extended the heirarchy too far for XML so I've tried commenting out the highest their classes one at a time, still get the same result though.

Would appreciate being pointed back in the right direction, thanks!

```
namespace ThereIsOnlyRules
{
[Serializable]
public class ArmyListing
{

    //[XmlElement("army")]
    //public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Army> army { get; set; }

    public void SerializeToXML(ArmyListing armyListing)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArmyListing));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\40k.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, armyListing);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Army
{
    //public Army();

    //[XmlAttribute]
    [XmlArray("unit-category")]
    public List<UnitCategory> unitCategory { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string armyName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class UnitCategory
{
    //public UnitCategory();

    [XmlArray("unit-type")]
    public List<UnitType> unitType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitCategoryName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class UnitType
{
    //public UnitType();

    [XmlArray("unit")]
    public List<Unit> unit { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitTypeName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Unit
{
    //public Unit();

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string unitName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("composition")]
    public string compsition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("weapon-skill")]
    public string weaponSkill { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("ballistic-skill")]
    public string ballisticSkill { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("strength")]
    public string strength { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("toughness")]
    public string T { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("wounds")]
    public string wounds { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("initiative")]
    public string initiative { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("attacks")]
    public string attacks { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("leadership")]
    public string leadership { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("saving-throw")]
    public string saveThrow { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("armour")]
    public string armour { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("weapons")]
    public string weapons { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("special-rules")]
    public string specialRules { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("dedicated-transport")]
    public string dedicatedTransport { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("options")]
    public string options { get; set; }
}


}
namespace ThereIsOnlyRules
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //ArmyListing armyListing = new ArmyListing();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ArmyListing armyListing = new ArmyListing();
        Army army = new Army();
        UnitCategory unitCategory = new UnitCategory();
        UnitType unitType = new UnitType();
        Unit unitList = new Unit();

        armyListing.army = new List<Army>();
        army.unitCategory = new List<UnitCategory>();
        unitCategory.unitType = new List<UnitType>();
        unitType.unit = new List<Unit>();

        army.armyName = "Tyranid";

        unitCategory.unitCategoryName = "Troops";
        unitType.unitTypeName = "Infantry";

        unitList.armour = "Chitin";
        unitList.attacks = "3";
        unitList.ballisticSkill="100";
        unitList.compsition="20";
        unitList.dedicatedTransport = "No";
        unitList.initiative = "3";
        unitList.leadership = "5";
        unitList.options = "8";
        unitList.saveThrow = "6+";
        unitList.specialRules ="None";
        unitList.strength = "3";
        unitList.T = "4";
        unitList.unitName = "Hornmagant";
        unitList.weapons = "Many";
        unitList.weaponSkill = "3";
        unitList.wounds = "1";

        //List<Unit> unit = new List<Unit>();
        //List<UnitType> unitType = new List<UnitType>();
        //List<UnitCategory> unitCategory = new List<UnitCategory>();
        //List<Army> army = new List<Army>();

        //Dictionary<ArmyListing, Army> armylist = new Dictionary<ArmyListing,Army>();

        armyListing.SerializeToXML(armyListing);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are adding `army` to `armyLising.army`, or setting any other child properties in your hierarchy.

Comment: A couple of minor stylistic points: Classes, methods and properties usually begin with capitals and if you're using properties, you can use object initialisers to clean up your creation code, like this: `UnitList list = new UnitList { Armour = "Chitin", Attacks = 3 //...etc };` Obviously formatted a bit better, but you get the idea.

Comment: To be honest the only reason I am doing this is so I can do it in reverse and deserialize from the XML, so I don't need to hardcode that data.
I will use that in future though!

XML tag formmating was confusing me. This isn't pointless though, I will hook the properties up to textboxes later.

Comment: FYI, `[Serializable]` isn't used by the XML Serializer. Also, how do you know there were no exceptions when you're eating all exceptions. Don't do that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Can you explain what you mean by "eating all the exceptions"... as long as I have the sections of code that can throw exceptions within a Try-Catch there shouldn't be any left unhandled?
Not clear to me best pracitise or whatnot that I have broken.

Comment: You are catching the exceptions and doing nothing with them. You won't know that they have occurred. You should not catch exceptions unless there is somethings specific that you need to do in order to correct them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your object creation code.  You new up all of those objects, but you never tie them together.  What ends up happening is that you pass a completely empty ArmyListing object to the serializer.  It's correct behavior as coded.

add

`armyListing.army.Add(army)`

and you'll see that you start to get some output.

Comment: Thanks, after I saw what "army" contained I pieced it together.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful feature for this task is [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), which have been introduced since C# 3.0.

So here is how object and collection initializers can be used (please note that I am using **PascalCase for properties instead of camelCase**):

```
public static void Test()
{
    UnitCategory troopsCategory = new UnitCategory
        {
            UnitCategoryName = "Troops",
            UnitType = new List<UnitType>
                {
                    new UnitType
                        {
                            UnitTypeName = "Infantry",
                            Unit = new List<Unit>
                                {
                                    new Unit
                                        {
                                            Armour = "Chitin",
                                            Attacks = "3",
                                            BallisticSkill = "100",
                                            Compsition = "20",
                                            DedicatedTransport = "No",
                                            Initiative = "3",
                                            Leadership = "5",
                                            Options = "8",
                                            SaveThrow = "6+",
                                            SpecialRules = "None",
                                            Strength = "3",
                                            T = "4",
                                            UnitName = "Hornmagant",
                                            Weapons = "Many",
                                            WeaponSkill = "3",
                                            Wounds = "1"                                               
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        };

    Army army = new Army
    {
        ArmyName = "Tyranid",
        UnitCategory = new List<UnitCategory>
            {
                troopsCategory
            }
    };

    ArmyListing armyListing = new ArmyListing
    {
        Army = new List<Army>
                {
                    army
                }
    };

    armyListing.SerializeToXml(armyListing);
}
```

By the way, `using` statement is better than manual closing:

```
public void SerializeToXml(ArmyListing armyListing)
{
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ArmyListing));
        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Test\40k.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, armyListing);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```